# CLion - No option to create Cmakelists.txt for a non-Cmake project

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

How do I generate Cmakelists.txt for a non-Cmake project in CLion? I have no idea why the documentation and other answers say that there's supposed to be "Tools -> Cmake" in the menu bar but I don't see any such option in my version (2023.2.2).

The documentation also tells you exactly how to create `Cmakelists.txt` for a non-Cmake project, this is what it says:

[image]

But this is how my project looks like:

[image]

What's wrong?

PS: I'm running WSL as my default toolchain.

Expecting to create cmakelists.txt for a non-cmake project as the documentations says, but can't find any option to do so.